# Scrape a specific text from a JavaScript code string

Tags: python, xpath, python-requests, scrapy

I would like to get the value of `uuid` key in the below text. Can I achieve this with `XPATH`?
I am scraping this value from a website source code.

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            var infoTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#vehicle-person-template').html());
            var summaryTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#vehicle-summary-template').html());

            axios.post("https:\/\/www.merinfo.se\/ajax\/vehicles", {
                    uuid: "21ac0674-488a-11e8-9b40-47e7b0ba95bc"                    })
                .then(function (response) {
                    $('#vehicle-info').html(infoTemplate(response.data.data));
                    $('#vehicle-summary').html(summaryTemplate(response.data.data));
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    $("#vehicle-info").html('<p class="font-italic mb-0">Fordonsinformation ej tillgängligt för tillfället</p>');
                    $('#vehicle-summary').html('<p class="font-italic mb-0">Fordonsinformation ej tillgängligt för tillfället</p>');
                });
        });

        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            var source = $("#person-residence-template").html();
            var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

            axios.post("https:\/\/www.merinfo.se\/api\/v1\/person\/residence", {
                    uuid: "21ac0674-488a-11e8-9b40-47e7b0ba95bc"                    })
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (typeof response.data.data !== 'undefined') {
                        $('#residence-info').html(template(response.data.data));
                    } else {
                        $("#residence-info").html('<p class="font-italic mb-0">Vi saknar bostadsinformation för Björn</p>');
                    }
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    $("#residence-info").html('<p class="font-italic mb-0">Vi saknar bostadsinformation för Björn</p>');
                });
        });
```

Comment: Have you consider using regular expressions?

Comment: I have no understanding of Regular Expression.

Comment: I will live you an answer using it and explained

Comment: That's so nice of you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the JS code as text you could use regular expressions to get that value.

### Code

```py
import re

pattern = r'uuid:\s\"(.*?)\"'
uuids = re.findall(pattern, code_text)
```

Assuming you have the code in the `code_text` variable.

`uuids` is a list with all the uuids in the code.

### Pattern explanation

- `uuid:` : The literal text 'uuid:'
- `\s` : Followed by a space
- `\"` : Then the open quotes
- `(.*?)` : Any characters (and making a group with this characters, this is the value you want)
- `\"` : Then the closing quotes

The `?` after the `.*` is for stopping matching any character if a `"` is encounter. If you don't put this `?` then it would match until the last `"` of the code.

The `(` and `)` creates a group, and `findall` will give as result all groups values in a list, in this case, all inside the quotes, the value you want.

Comment: You can check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/4ZVhwt/3)

Comment: Good to know :)